# SQL DELETE - Error Parsing the Query

Tags: sql, parsing, token, offset, sql-delete

I'm working on a small expenses/income tracking C# console program that interfaces with a Compact SQL Server (.sdf). The database stores the expenses and a simple command line input allows the user to delete an entry based upon an index number in the DB. Here is the error I'm getting.

**"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 32,Token in error = Index ]"**

Below is the code that removes an entry.

```
else if (ans.Equals("REMOVE"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Which entry?");
            deleteTrans(Console.ReadLine(), conn);
            displayDB(conn);
        }
}

static void deleteTrans(string index, SqlCeConnection conn)
    {

        SqlCeCommand deleteCmd = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE FROM Transactions WHERE Index=" + index, conn);
        try
        {
            deleteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlCeException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You failed!\n" + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

The database has 5 columns (Date, Description, Amount, Code, Index)

**Date** - Data Type(bigint) - Length(8) - Allow Nulls(Yes) - Unique(No) - Prim Key(No)

**Description** - Data Type(ncarchar) - Length(50) - Allow Nulls(Yes) - Unique(No) - Prim Key(No)

**Amount** - Data Type(money) - Length(19) - Allow Nulls(No) - Unique(No) - Prim Key(No)

**Code** - Data Type(nvarchar) - Length(4) - Allow Nulls(No) - Unique(No) - Prim Key(No)

**Index** - Data Type(bigint) - Length(8) - Allow Nulls(No) - Unique(Yes) - Prim Key(No)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Index` is a [reserved word in SQL CE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173340.aspx), so you need to put it in square brackets, or (better) rename the column to not use a reserved word.

In addition, you should parameterize your query instead of generating it dynamically, like this:

```
SqlCeCommand deleteCmd = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE FROM Transactions WHERE [Index]=@Index", conn);
var indParam = new SqlCeParameter("@Index", SqlDbType.BigInt, int.Parse(index));
deleteCmd.Parameters.Add(indParam);
try
{
    deleteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlCeException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You failed!\n" + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Yes I managed to get this updated query to work. Thank you very much. I changed Index to IndexVar in the table schema and I also parameterized my queries. Thanks again!